# Is Group $G$ has element of order $35$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

While solving set of questions on group theory. I saw this question. It is multiple choice question.

Question: let $G$ be finite group, having normal subgroups $H$, and $K$ of order $25$ and $14$ respectively. Then choose the correct options.

(a) $G$ has element of order $5$

(b) $G$ has element of order $7$

(c) $G$ has element of order $35$

(d)  none of these.

My attempt: as $5$, $7$ are primes & divides $o(G)$ so, $G$ must have element of orders $5$, $7$ (By Cauchy theorem) Hence options (a), and (b) must be true!

But I am not sure about (c). Please help.

Comment: The product of an element of order $5$ and an element of order $7$ will have order $35$

Comment: Is $G$ a finite group?

Comment: Yes G is finite group

Comment: Clearly, if there were such an element, it would probably be the product of an element of order $5$ and an element of order $7$. Normally, it wouldn't be so easy, but you've been given additional information: normality of two subgroups. Can you exploit that normality to show that that product indeed has order $35$?

Comment: @AbishankaSaha That's not necessarily true. The group isn't assumed to be abelian. In $S_7$, for instance, the product of an element of order $7$ and an element of order $5$ has order $7$.

Comment: I am confused, because group $S_3$ has elements of order $2$, $3$ but it doesn't have element of order $6$. So is here $G$ will have element of order $5×7$?

Comment: The answer is yes, the group has an element of order $7$. Do you see that the group will have a subgroup of order $25\cdot 7$? Do you know Sylow's theorems?

Comment: What can you say about $HK$?

Comment: I know $HK$ will be normal in $G$ of order $25×14$. But then what?

Comment: Can you show $HK=KH$?

Comment: You have that $H$ and $K$ are normal, and $H \cap K = 1$. So what kind of product is $HK$?

Comment: @Arthur Yes I know that. I just gave a hint, the rest follows from $HK=KH$, right?

Comment: @AbishankaSaha $HK = KH$ is not sufficient to conclude that elements of $H$ commute with elements of $K$. For example, if $G = S_3$ and $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of orders $2$ and $3$, then we have $|HK| = |KH| = 6$, hence both $HK$ and $KH$ equal $G$. But elements of order $2$ and $3$ do not commute in $S_3$. (All you can conclude from $HK = KH$ is that $HK$ is a subgroup. In fact, $HK = KH$ if and only if $HK$ is a subgroup. Neither $H$ nor $K$ need be normal for this to occur.)

Comment: @Abhshanka. After some reading/recalling the concepts, what I got is!! $HK= KH$ "doesn't" imply each element of $H$ commutes with each element of $K$. For eg: you can see in $S_3$.  The key here is, If $H$, $K$ normal in $G$ with $H ∩K = {e}$ then each element in $H$ commutes with each element in $K$

Answer (score 3):

Take an element $h\in H $ of order 5 and $k\in K $ of order 7. Prove that $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\in H\cap K $ (due to $H $, $K $ being normal subgroups). Because orders of $H $ and $K $ are coprime, $H\cap K $ is trivial so $h $ and $k $ commute. Thus, $(hk)^j=h^jk^j $ for $j\in\mathbb Z $ and you can use that to prove that the order of $hk $ is 35.

Comment: I don't get it. I have counter example! Take $S_3$ it has subgroup of order $2$ and $3$ whose intersection is trivial! but elements of order $2$ and $3$ does not commute!

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Your counter example doesn't work. Is the subgroup of order $2$ normal in $S_3$?

Comment: No in $S_3$ subgroup of order 2,  is not normal.

Answer (score 0):

$G$ has subgroups of order $5$ and order $7$ since subgroup of order $5$ is normal because any group of order $p^2$ is abelian and all subgroups of abelian group are normal so by this here is existence of group subgroup 's product to be subgroup.